# using RX Framework to implement the Observable Pattern

Tags: c#, .net, observer-pattern

I would like to implement an Observer that listens for both PropertyChanging, and PropertyChanged events of a property. Then when PropertyChanging is triggered, I need to be able to cancel the event entirely, or change the value to something else. Is it possible to do this with the RX Framework?

Answer (score 0):

In my viewmodel within my SaveCommand I have this.

```
Observable.FromEventPattern(this, "PropertyChanged").Subscribe(_ => SaveCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged());
```

I have this for Observing my IsBusy property right now, but it observes the entire viewmodel. I'm hoping to find a way to just observe a single property instead of the entire object.